mysql select list name join on find_in_set list id
list name with join from other table
t1 
id  orderid items
1   1001    1,2,5
2   1002    5,3
3   1003    2,4

t2 
id   name
1    item1
2    item2
3    item3
4    item4
5    item5

Need to result select statement like by using join ,GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET because have 58k in order table
orderid  itemNames 
1001     item1,item2,item5
1002     item5,item3 
1003     item2,item4

select v.orderid,sub.itemNames from t1 as v 
LEFT JOIN 
(select id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) as itemnames from t2) 
 AS sub  ON FIND_IN_SET(sub.id,v.items ) 

not working

Change your table design and stop storing the items IDs as a CSV list.

can not understand ! give me example

SELECT t1.orderid, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) itemNames
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.items)
GROUP BY 1


Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

@Tyler2P again... the fact that the answer is code-only and does not contain the explanations does not mean that the explanations are needed at all.

If a reader (not specifically the OP) is new to SQL, they may not understand the code snippet without at least a little bit of an explanation. It's better to think of everyone, not just the OP.
